# pkgsrc, ports, portage, macports etc

Tags: linux, package

I wonder if we can a reduce just a little bit the effort around packages
under linux/unix OS environments and software installations.
It is my stance that there is too much redundant effort about $subject.

I have been pondering about ways to connect build systems of $subject
with some next "stage build tools", like: easybuild (1) & openbuildservice (2);
read below for more details.

To be more specific, I was able last week to take pkgsrc's repository,
process the Makefiles via a tiny "pkg2eb" script and produce *.eb files
for easybuild, then fed many parallel gcc compilations with them.
That "blindly-driven process" ended up in >600 successful builds,
ie. these were packages that simply needed 'wget/configure/make/make install';
It's not bad for a first run, just wonder if it can be done any better.

So:

According to your experience, which OS has the cleanest/leanest
pkgsrc/port structure to be sourced & fed to other external tools?
This is NOT the same as which has the most available packages!

Have you heard of any similar efforts trying to massively produce
packages from eg. a common source list in a structured manner?
(I mean, in a transferable way across different build systems)

Comment: This one is an interesting relevant resource:
"package manager comparisons: the ports", dated 2007-11-11
http://cowbert.livejournal.com/166343.html

Answer (score 1):

So,

much relevant information is visible here:
http://www.mancoosi.org/edos/packages/ # lengthy description of various packaging formats

this one shows the higher level picture:
http://www.mancoosi.org/edos/suggestions/ (esp. 2.1.1  Expressivity shortcomings)

Anyway, to answer to original question, the best bets as of now are:

- RPM's .spec files
- DEB control files
- pkgsrc; possible but some hackery is still needed
- portage; quite clean, distinguishes between DEPEND and RDEPEND
- macports; easy to parse; very detailed dependencies aspects
- ports; like pkgsrc; multiple dependencies defined